# Excel: Return / Wordwrap / Second or more lines in firstpage.footer?

Tags: excel, vba, footer

i'd like to Change my footers via VBA.

- Companyname
- Path and Filename

i can change the standardfooter by

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&7My Company" & Chr(10) & "&Z&F"
```

but i cant change the FirstPage.Footer to get a wordwrap

My Code is `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text "&7My Company" & Chr(10) & "&Z&F"`

but i only get 'My Comany' and no second line.

Any suggestions?

Hallo zusammen,

wie bekomme ich einen Zeilenumbruch in die Fußzeile der ersten Seite?

Viele Grüße

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&ZMy Company" & Chr(10) & "Path and Filename"`?

Comment: Now i did, 
i get a second line, but the Text 'Path and Filename'

I Also tried:

* .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = .LeftFooter (->one line)

* =ActiveWorkbook.name (-> second Line, but Workbookname as Text and not changing

Comment: Jus change the `Path and Filename` with the real path and filename. You can save both of them into a variable, and concatenate.

Comment: no, sorry, i need the placeholder / variable for the filename/path in the file, so it will change with every SaveAs